# How to reverse the the gluLookat transform for a specific object in scene?

Tags: opengl, transformation

I have the following scene.

```
     glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
     glLoadIdentity ();
     gluPerspective(45, w/h,.1, 100);

     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
     glLoadIdentity();
     gluLookAt(cameraX,cameraY,cameraZ,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);

         drawtheBOT();
         drawUserTrackedBall();  // This ball moves in 3d with user controlling it.
```

When i change the values of cameraX,cameraY,cameraZ the ball movements also change based on the glulookat values. for example if I am looking from a positive x direction my original left and right movements will become near and far movements now.

How do i cancel the lookat transformation?

Answer (score 0):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

drawUserTrackedBall();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();
```

or

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glPushMatrix();
gluLookAt(cameraX,cameraY,cameraZ,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
drawtheBOT();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();

drawUserTrackedBall();  // This ball moves in 3d with user controlli
```

or

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrix(bot_modelview);
drawtheBOT();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrix(ball_modelview);
drawUserTrackedBall();
```

The calls of glMatrixMode are not redundant, because I don't know what happens inside of the drawing functions.